# How to create custom toggle button in tinymce?

Tags: tinymce

I know how to create a basic button with no state. I created two buttons that output custom list styles by outputting ul's with a certain class that is styled in the CSS. But now I would like for the buttons to have a state whereby if I click button 1 and then click button 2, button 1 is disabled and button 2 is enabled and if I click on a custom list style item with button 2 state, button 2 becomes active.

Comment: If you're asking about how to accomplish this in TinyMCE, then the question is [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as questions about third-party plugins are off-topic. But if you want a pure code solution, check [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828998/multiple-toggle-buttons-html) for help with that.

Comment: what are you trying to build that needs this?